# How does WordPress rewrite URLS using its PHP scripts

Tags: php, url-rewriting, php.ini

My Question is `WordPress` redirects url even in `httpd`. `httpd` doesn't support htaccess. And if developer tries to rewrite urls he have to do it in the httpd.conf file.
But `WordPress` how rewrite urls in httpd? If anyone have idea please answer.

Comment: sorry, but right now it is impossible to understand what is it you are asking. For example, what does it mean "httpd doesn't support htaccess"

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can make redirects internally, by [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function. It is php code, for it to function, no redirect in Apache (httpd) or Nginx web server is needed.

Also, WordPress has own [rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), accessible via `add_rewrite_rule()` and similar functions. This is also php code, which doesn't require any support from a web server.

Comment: The question seems to be about rewrite rules, not redirects.